# MYSQL: function truncate(numeric,int) does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, truncate

I would like to round very long numbers and the *ROUND()* function works very well here, but still the length of the number is the same.

I used:
`ROUND(152.23456789123456789,1)`

And got: 152.20000000000000000

**But would like to get: 152.2**

I read that there is the *TRUNCATE()* function which "cuts" the decimal numbers, but this doesn't work for me. I got an error message saying that the function does not exists or permission is denied. I am using Vertica.
The function I tryed is:
`TRUNCATE(152.23456789123456789,1)`

I also read that adding a third argument to the round function may help, but this also doesn't work for me, again because the function does not exist:
`ROUND(152.23456789123456789,1,1)`

Do you know what I could do alternatively?

Thank you!

Comment: The trailing zeros have nothing to do with the ***value*** and everything to do with the ***data-type*** and how that data-type is presented on screen as a string.  So, the questions which arise in my mind are: ***1).*** Why is `152.20000000000000000` not suitable for you, when mathematically it ***is*** equal to `152.2`?  ***2).*** What is the data-type of the value you're truncating/rounding?  ***3).*** Where is the result going to be used/stored, and what data-type does that destination expect?  ***4).*** Have you tried casting the result to a different data-type?

Comment: *And got: 152.20000000000000000* Not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18bae0c3bc4cf9e4f0732a2204561d3a This may be your client "service".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROUND()` affects the *value* of the columns, but not necessarily the *type*.

If you want one decimal place, then convert to a decimal:

```
CAST(152.23456789123456789 as DECIMAL(10, 1))
```

If you start with a floating point type, then the result is going to be floating point -- and the extra zeros are probably coming from that (however you are querying the data).

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e9ce171de9e699501c3cd6182faba876) is an example that shows the difference in types.